# smallest perimeter of compound shape

Tags: area, square-numbers, sums-of-squares, constants

If you have a compound shape made of three unique squares with fixed sizes, what is the smallest possible perimeter for that shape? assuming no overlaps.

Comment: Hi spydragon, when you say fixed sizes, do you mean that you are given three side  lengths $a,b,c$ and 3 squares of these side lengths?

Comment: @CalvinKhor Hello, what I mean is that the three squares with side lengths $a, b, \text{and} c$ have fixed areas,(there side lengths will not change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the squares $A,B,C$ have respective side lengths $a\le b\le c$.

The total perimeter will be $4a+4b+4c$ less the lengths of any common edges of  each pair of $A,B,C$. (If two squares have a length $l$ in common then we must subtract $2l$).

The maximum possible lengths of common edges are $2a,2a,2b$ and so the minimum perimeter is $2b+4c$. This minimum can be achieved if $c\ge a+b$ since we can simply put both $A$ and $B$ on the same edge of $C$.

If, however, $c<a+b$ then the same arrangement as before is best but now the length of the common edges is only $2a+2c$. The perimeter is therefore $2a+4b+2c$.

Comment: if $a \ge b \ge c$ then how is $c \ge  a+b$ possible?

Comment: Sorry - typo in line 1

Comment: ok, that makes more sense.

Comment: I just checked that, and when you have $a=2, b=4, \text{and } c=6$ it doesn't work. your equation gives me $40$, but the smallest I got was $32$

Comment: Yes you're right . When there is a common edge of length $l$ say, I should have subtracted $2l$. It's now amended.

Comment: when you said "The maximum possible lengths of common edges are $2a,2a,2b$" did you mean to put $a$ twice?

Comment: Where A and B meet two lengths of $a$ are eliminated. Similarly where A and C meet.